# How to fix overlapping hexagons with geom_hex() and ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I am plotting some data, basically I have coordinates and a value for each point. I wanted to make a hexagon map, with each hexagon averaging all the point values that correspond to that hexagon.

I manage to produce the map, but the some of the hexagons are overlapping and I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
pp = ggplot(df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill=value, group=value)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 50, linewidth = 10) 
pp
```

And the plot:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hexagons to be colored according to the average `value`, you will need `stat_summary_hex`, passing the numeric value to the `z` aesthetic, which by default is averaged in each hex bin.

Don't group by `value` - this effectively creates a layer of hexbins for each `value`, and this is what leads to the bins being in different positions in each group. Also, the values can't be averaged if they are in different groups.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
  stat_summary_hex(aes(z = as.numeric(as.character(value))),
                   bins = 50, linewidth = 10) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = scales::hue_pal()(5))
```

[image]

Note that the latest CRAN version of ggplot has an issue with hex-binning, and you will need to install the development version to get a decent result here. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75002245/inaccurate-mapping-of-gradient-fill-colours-with-bin-counts-in-geom-hexbin-in) for further details.

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(1000, 5.5), lat = rnorm(1000, 52.5),
                 value = factor(sample(0:4, 1000, TRUE)))
```

Comment: Man thanks a lot for this! I had no idea about that bug, really helpful!